# PHP - Search and replace between two positions of a sentence

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace 'he' by 'she' between two given positions, in this case between Maria(0) and Peter(34). So basically I give two positions and replace all the occurrences in the sentence between the boundaries. I have tried with the following simple code but it seems that the substr_replace function doesn't allow me to do it. Any idea to make it works?

```
$sentence = "Maria went to London where he met Peter with his family.";
$clean = substr_replace($sentence, "he", "she", 0, 34);
```

Comment: The docs for substr_replace would show you it doesn't take that many parameters. Just make substrings and do the replace on them, then put the whole back together.

Comment: Do the positions 0 and 34 actually matter? Or would you be even happier to see "replace between Maria and Peter"?

Comment: Thanks, @developerwjk I have looked different PHP functions to make it but I was a bit lost since it's the first time I'm dealing with regular expressions.

Comment: @zx81 Yes, I'm using arrays of positions so I can't use the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using *[substr_replace()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)* incorrectly, and in this case you don't need it. Instead, try this, using a combo of [*str_replace()*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [*substr()*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$sentence = "Maria went to London where he met Peter with his family.";
$clean = str_replace(' he ', ' she ', substr($sentence, 0, 34));
$clean .= substr($sentence, 34);
```

[**See demo**](http://3v4l.org/Zn0XS)

Essentially, you are replacing `he` with `she` on the specified substr of `$sentence`, then concatenating the rest of `$sentence` back on.

Note the spaces around `' he '` and `' she '`. This is necessary because otherwise you would replace `where` with `wshere`.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark, this is exactly what I was looking for because this is just an example but I will have some arrays of positions in order to determinate where to make the replaces.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: mark made me realized I misinterpretted your question. However I feel you might still find this regex useful, so I'm going to leave my answer but for the answer to your exact question look at MarkM's answer.

If you want to replace all instances of the word he with she only when the word 'he' occurs as its own word I would do something like this.

```
$pattern = '/(\b)he(\b)/';
$replacement = '$1she$2';
$subject = 'Maria went to London where he met Peter with his family';

$newString = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

The regex pattern basically says find all instances of the letters 'he' surrounded by valid word seperators (\b) and replace it with 'she' surrounded by the word separators that were found.

Edit:

**[See It Run](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/487cdaa04757e94b5487686597fcdabb352ab6e2)**

Comment: This replaces *all* occurrences of `he`. I believe OP only wants replacement "between two positions of a sentence."

Comment: @MarkM You're correct, I misinterpreted the question. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks echochamber but Mark is rigth I need to specify the boundaries with the positions to replace it only between them.